# Android List Below Toggle Buttons

Tags: android

I have a list that is intended to be below toggle buttons. The list grabs data from a server and then parses them. My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textOff="Apps"
        android:textOn="Apps" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggle_button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textOff="VMs"
        android:textOn="VMs" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggle_button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textOff="Groups"
        android:textOn="Groups" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toggle_button1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for the actual fragment:

```
public class ProblemFragment extends SherlockListFragment
{
    private SeparatedListAdapter list;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getSherlockActivity().setContentView(R.layout.problem_layout);

        list = new SeparatedListAdapter(this.getSherlockActivity(), new Layout(R.layout.separated_list_adapter_two_text, R.id.two_text_title, R.id.two_text_desc));
        ToggleButton b1 = (ToggleButton) this.getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.toggle_button1);
        ToggleButton b2 = (ToggleButton) this.getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.toggle_button2);
        ToggleButton b3 = (ToggleButton) this.getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.toggle_button3);

        setListAdapter(list);
        refresh();
    }

    public void refresh()
    {
        list = new SeparatedListAdapter(this.getSherlockActivity(), new Layout(R.layout.separated_list_adapter_two_text, R.id.two_text_title, R.id.two_text_desc));
        refreshStats();
    }

    public void refreshStats()
    {
        //Omitted parsing code

        list.addSection(new String("Hello world!!"));
        setListAdapter(list);
    }
}
```

However, when I use setListAdapter(list), the buttons are overwritten. They are visible before the app retrieves the data and parses it, but they are overwritten after I call setListAdapter. How can i fix this?

Comment: Change the `android:layout_toRightOf` of the second toggle button to `android:layout_toRightOf=@id/toggle_button1`. Maybe this was the cause.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error with obfuscation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove

```
 android:orientation="horizontal"
```

from your root `layout`. `RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `orientation` property. Also, `weight` is for child elements of a `LinearLayout` and when you use it then you should assign the `width` of each child view to `0dp` for horizontal `orientation` and `height="0dp"` for vertical `orientation`.

Then wrap your `ToggleButtons` in a `LinearLayout`, vertical or horizontal `orientation`, and give it the property

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

then give your `ListView` the property

```
android:layout_below="@id/idOfLinearLayout"
```

So it may look something like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/toggleLL"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Apps"
        android:textOn="Apps" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="VMs"
        android:textOn="VMs" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Groups"
        android:textOn="Groups" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toggleLL" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also removed the `RelativeLayout` properties from the `ToggleButtons` since they are now wrapped in a `LinearLayout`. And you had a circular view error there with assigning the second `ToggleButton` to the right of itself which may have been a copy/paste error. Hope this helps.

**Note** that the default `orientation` for a `LinearLayout` is `horizontal` so leaving that property out will give you that effect.

Comment: Thanks!!
I tried the exact code you supplied, but the list still overwrites the buttons.
Is there anything else I could have done wrong?
I am using setListAdapter; does this make it act as though it were using fill_parent?

Comment: Sorry, check my code again. I didn't get it all formatted so parts were left out

Comment: No, I went in (edit) and copied the entire thing as it is already :/

Comment: I just changed the `height` of the root `layout` (the `RelativeLayout`). Try that, it should work

Comment: Nope, didn't do anything.
Could it be the adapter itself?

Comment: Maybe if you are using a custom `Adapter`. But this should work...I use it all of the time.

Comment: I did just notice that I didn't change the `height` of the `RelativeLayout` as I thought I did so you could try that but still should have worked.

Comment: What should the height have been?

Comment: Ok, it would be right now. I just went back through it. Sorry, I hurried when I wrote and edited it. It should be correct now...long day

Comment: Sigh. Still not working. I'm definitely starting to think it's a code issue. I'll add the code up in the main post.

Comment: I've added the code for the actual fragment to the main page, with a few omissions.

Comment: Man, I don't see what could be causing it...frustrating. I've never used `SherlockListFragment` but I'm not sure what that would have to do with it. So, its still hiding your `ToggleButtons` when your `list` populates or has anything changed?

Comment: Yeah. The three toggle buttons pop up, and, when the app calls "setListAdapter" (interesting to note, the second one, in refreshStats; when the list is empty, the buttons remain just fine), the list takes up the whole screen.

Comment: These may not be the problem but why are you calling `refresh()` directly after setting the `Adapter`. Also, its more efficient to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter` then setting it again

Comment: Good point. Thanks for that. Changed.
What's interesting is that when I align the buttons to the bottom of the screen (or anywhere that the list is not), they stay there just fine. The issue seems to be with the list autoaligning itself to the top of the screen.

Comment: That is strange. You could try using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for your `ListView` but I'm still confused on why the other way isn't working...always does for me

Comment: I was going to blame my custom adapter, but then I tried with an ArrayAdapter with two elements and it still overwrites the buttons.

Comment: setListAdapter was replacing the default ListFragment list, not the custom myList. All I did was create a new ListView that read from the XML and then set itself visible. However, all my onClicks are not working (both on the toggles and the list), and I have no clue what's up with that.

Comment: I completely missed that you weren't using `myList`! I got nothing on the `onClick()`s not working right now. Do you know if at least the `ToggleButtons` were working before? Anyway, if you don't get it figured out post a new question with relevant code and explanation and I will take a look if I see it...this post has gotten kind of long ;)

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I can not test your XML but I think that you need scrollbars! If the list is filled with a lot of entries, it can became bigger that the screen, making the buttons disappear because they are *pushed* up by the list. Try to add a scroll to the whole layout.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <!-- Original layout here -->

   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Of course, if you just put only one layout inside the scrollview, there is no need for the outer layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

               <!-- Original layout here -->

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: [From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)"You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView."